# JComponent.repaint() doesn't respond

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

I trying to make an app for solving a Rubik Cube.I'm using Eclipse IDE with Java 8. So far, I encountered a problem: I'm trying to paint my initial cube configuration(just the front face, so far). After that, I want to change the color of a square, just to see it works.
The good part: it is rendering.
The problem is: it is updating the color, but it isn't repainting() on the JFrame. Down below, I attached my code.
It is the first time I'm playing with controls rendering, and I don't really know how to properly use it.
**Main Menu Constructor:**(The JFrame where I want to render the cube)

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1002, 593);
        contentPane = new JPanel();

        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JButton solveButton = new JButton("Solve");
        solveButton.setBounds(46, 59, 270, 33);
        panel.add(solveButton);

        JButton btnChangeConfiguration = new JButton("Change Configuration");
        btnChangeConfiguration.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ChangeConfigMenu configMenuPanel=new ChangeConfigMenu();
                configMenuPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        btnChangeConfiguration.setBounds(46, 105, 270, 33);
        panel.add(btnChangeConfiguration);

        cubeRenderArea.setBounds(12, 13, 551, 520);
        contentPane.add(cubeRenderArea);
        cubeRenderArea.setLayout(null);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_R) {
                    System.out.println("Refreshing...");
                    cubeRenderArea.repaint();
                    cubeRenderArea.ListCubies();
                }
                if(e.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.VK_C) {
                    cubeRenderArea.setCubieColor(2, 2, Color.RED);
                }
            }
        });
```

**RectDraw Class:**(used to control the JPanel where the cube should appear)

```
    public static final int PREFERRED_WIDTH=100;
    public static final int PREFERRED_HEIGHT=100;
    public final int cubieWidth=100;
    public final int offset=50;

    private RubikCube rubikCube=new RubikCube();


    public void setCubieColor(int cubieRowIndex,int cubieColumnIndex,Color preferredColor) {
        rubikCube.getCubie(cubieRowIndex-1,cubieColumnIndex-1).setColor(preferredColor);
        //repaint();
    }
    public RectDraw() {
        super();
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        rubikCube=new RubikCube();
        //Front Face
        g.setColor(rubikCube.getCubie(0).getColor());
        g.drawRect(32+offset, 32+offset, 100, 100);
        g.fillRect(32+offset, 32+offset, 100, 100);

        g.setColor(rubikCube.getCubie(1).getColor());
        g.drawRect(32+cubieWidth+10+offset, 32+offset, 100, 100);
        g.fillRect(32+cubieWidth+10+offset, 32+offset, cubieWidth, cubieWidth);

        g.setColor(rubikCube.getCubie(2).getColor());
        g.drawRect(32+2*cubieWidth+20+offset, 32+offset, cubieWidth, cubieWidth);
        g.fillRect(32+2*cubieWidth+20+offset, 32+offset, cubieWidth, cubieWidth);

        g.setColor(rubikCube.getCubie(3).getColor());
        g.drawRect(32+offset, 32+offset+cubieWidth+10, 100, 100);
        g.fillRect(32+offset, 32+offset+cubieWidth+10, 100, 100);
        //I'm doing this 5 more times with different coordinates.
    }
}
```

**RubikCube Class**(It is used to set and manage all the cubies of my Rubiks's Cube)

```
    private ArrayList<Cubie> cubies;

    public RubikCube() {
        InitializeCubies();
    }
    private void InitializeCubies(){
        cubies=new ArrayList<Cubie>(27);
        for(int i=0;i<27;i++) {
            cubies.add(new Cubie(i/3,i%3,i,Color.BLACK));
        }
    }
    public Cubie getCubie(int index) {
        return cubies.get(index);
    }
    public Cubie getCubie(int rowIndex,int columnIndex) {
        for(Cubie cubie: cubies) {
            if(cubie.getRowIndex()==rowIndex && cubie.getColumnIndex()==columnIndex) {
                return cubie;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void setCubieColor(int rowIndex,int columnIndex,Color newColor) {
        cubies.get((rowIndex-1)*3+columnIndex).setColor(newColor);
    }
    public void setCubieColor(int serialIndex,Color newColor) {
        cubies.get(serialIndex).setColor(newColor);
    }
```

**Cubie Class:**

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class Cubie {
    private int rowIndex;
    private int columnIndex;
    private int serialIndex;
    private Color color;

    public Cubie() {
        rowIndex=0;
        columnIndex=0;
        serialIndex=0;
        color=Color.BLACK;
    }
    public Cubie(int newIndexRow,int newColumnIndex,int serialIndex,Color newColor) {
        this.rowIndex=newIndexRow;
        this.columnIndex=newColumnIndex;
        this.serialIndex=serialIndex;
        this.color=newColor;
    }
    public int getRowIndex() {
        return rowIndex;
    }
    public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
        this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
    }
    public int getColumnIndex() {
        return columnIndex;
    }
    public void setColumnIndex(int columnIndex) {
        this.columnIndex = columnIndex;
    }
    public int getSerialIndex() {
        return serialIndex;
    }
    public void setSerialIndex(int serialIndex) {
        this.serialIndex = serialIndex;
    }
    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }
    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Cubie[MatrixPos("+rowIndex+","+columnIndex+"),Color="+color+"];";
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to render a cubie's face on a JPanel.Then, everytime I press 'r'/'R' key I want to refresh(repaint) the cube JPanel and when I press 'c'/'C' the cubie in the middle of the square should change it's value.

I hope I wrote enough details to not get you confused :).If you can help me, I'd be grateful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LZ3K.png)
I upload an ss of my Main Menu, to see what it does, so far.The Key Listeners are working and they are updating the color, the problem is when I need to render it on the screen. 
[Main Menu view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LZ3K.png)

Comment: `repaint()` is asynchronous, meaning it doesn't repaint immediately (but should run very soon after you call it).  Painting also requires the use of the event dispatch thread, so if you're blocking or using that thread you won't get any repainting until you release it.

Comment: `cubeRenderArea` is undefined, could you show the code that defines (and initializes) it?

Comment: To follow up on @markspace 's great advice, repaint() will cause paint() to be called again on the EDT, and in swing, paint will call `paintComponent(); paintChildren();`

Comment: cubeRenderArea= new RectDraw();
cubeRenderArea.setBounds(12, 13, 551, 520);
contentPane.add(cubeRenderArea);
cubeRenderArea.setLayout(null); ------This is how I instantiate the JPanel

Comment: One thing that makes me nervous is calling `setBounds()` everywhere and removing the layout managers.  It's possible that without those components `repaint()` can't figure out how to redraw your objects.  It would be better to use `setPreferedSize()` and use a regular layout manager.

Comment: So....I tried to follow your advice, and this is what I came with:  `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
       contentPane.repaint();
      }
     }); `. This snippet is called every time 'R' key is pressed, but it still doesn't do anything useful(the cubie still remains the same color). Maybe the idea of repainting on a key-press event is not working.Am I doing something wrong? Or did I misunderstand your idea?  Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).